# Get mailto field from intent

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, share

I have put my app as option to share when I click on an email address.
How can get the field "mailto" from this intent?

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=mailto:xxxxxxx@xxxxx.xxx flg=0x3000000 cmp=net.a2system.yambing/.activities.ContactsChooser (has extras) }
```

I know it could be easy but i tried everything and i can't.
Thanks!

Comment: I have same problem if you find any way please share that here .

Answer (score 0):

Try use `intent.getData()` method.